# Run two instances of K3S on the same machine

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I'd like to run two instances of `k3s` on the same machine.

Let's say I have already two different master servers.

What I'd like to do is to install:

1. A K3S instance to deal with Master #1.
2. A second instance to deal with Master #2.

First instance will be managed by myself while the second instance will be managed by my customer.

Is there a way to setup two instances of K3S on the same machine?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question directly, hence the comment. You could use k3d (https://k3d.io), which runs k3s clusters in docker. You can have as many clusters as your machine can handle. Locally I have 1-3 clusters running at any given time (for dev, testing ..etc.).
Back to your question: One possibility is to chroot jail multiple k3s processes to separate them. Of course you would need some Linux knowledge for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running multiple instances of k3s is not supported out of the box.
You can however use tools like [k3d](https://k3d.io/) (running inside docker container), or [multipass-k3s](https://github.com/superseb/multipass-k3s) (running inside a VM).

chroot jail is not really an option. Rootless K3s is still in experimental stage <sup>[[reference](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/advanced/#running-k3s-with-rootless-mode-experimental)]</sup>, and applications running as root can easily break out of jail.

Comment: Finally made it works using vagrant and generating two VMs. Thanks for your help